# I would like to have a house in France, and “one” in California

Tags: pronoms

In English, I can say:

> I would like to have a house in France, and **one** in California.

the one is referring back to the original *house*, before the *and* splits the sentence.

Can I do the same thing in French? It always works on online translators, but they may be directly translating it. If it is valid, should it be *un* or *une*?

> Je voudrais avoir aussi une gîte en France et **un** à la plage en Californie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the same in French. The gender must be kept unchanged.

Your first sentence might be translated as:

> J'aimerais avoir une maison en France et une (autre) en Californie.

I would rewrite your second sentence like this:

> J'aimerais aussi avoir une maison en France et une autre sur la plage, en Californie.

Note that it is *un gîte*, not *une* unless you are talking about a boat heeling which is obviously not the case here.